# Extension from the Huawei Matebook D15

Tags: huawei-developers

I know you can build a Sata 3 SSD in a d15 with an adapter cable from the huawei shop... but can they also install an NVMe M.2 SSD? And if not, does anyone have an SSD with a good read and write rate?

I hope I can install a NVMe SSD

Comment: You already have an nvme SSD on your board, do you need more space or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install nvme, but will need an extension, https://www.amazon.com/nvme-sata-adapter/s?k=nvme+to+sata+adapter. Then your nvme will work at the sata3 speed 6GBPS.

[image]

[image]